# DICOM reconstruction tag

Tags: dicom

I'm look for a DICOM image reconstruction tag. Is there any tag to recognize a DICOM Image is result of a reconstruction?

First try searching for "**MPR**" (multiplanare Rekonstruktion) but just for Siemens?

```
(0008,0008);Image Type;DERIVED\PRIMARY\AXIAL\CT_SOM5 MPR
(0008,103e);Series Description;Abdomen nativ  3.0  MPR  kor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image Type (0008, 0008) is the field you are searching for. Unfortunately, you will run into three issues:

- Not all vendors stick to the defined terms for this attribute, some treat them as free text. So does Siemens - "CT_SOM5 MPR" is not a defined term for this attribute.
- it depends on the type of object (SOP Class UID) which defined terms apply and from which component of Image Type they can be obtained.

  - DERIVED\SECONDARY\MPR (MPR is value 3 for MR objects)
  - DERIVED\SECONDARY\ANGIO\RESAMPLED (RESAMPLED is value 4 for Enhanced IODs)
- There are several reconstruction techniques, MPR is just one of them

There is an attribute Volume Based Calculation Technique (0008, 9207) from which this could be safely determined, but so far I have never seen it included in practical datasets. Plus, it is not allowed for all IODs

Long story short: Using Image Type and sticking to the rules and defined terms applying to this attribute would be DICOM conformant and correct, but fail in some practical cases. I do not see any other generic approach. To include more practical cases, you will need to implement vendor-specific heuristics.

Comment: @kritzle_sw Thanks, very clear and helpful. Yes, I found no (0008,9207) tag here too.

Comment: @twyly thanks for the kind feedback. Actually, I wonder why you want to obtain this information ("reconstructed") programatically. If I knew the use case, maybe I could provide more useful advice.

Comment: | I try to analyse tons of different DICOM images from different manufacturers.

Comment: For the purpose of ...?

Comment: Get more wisdom for BfS... ;-).  I'm not working at BfS.  BTW, why is @name no more possible here? And my english is bad.

Comment: @twyly: BfS = Bundesamt für Strahlenschutz? So you want to distinguish between images for which x-rays were used and separate them from those which are secondary? Then it is *quite* safe to assume that: if Image Type value 1 is ORIGINAL, the image was *aquired*, otherwise, the image was calculated. Will not work in all cases but in much more than searching for a particular type of reconstruction.